# How do you use Three Ten Backport classes with JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc, threetenbp

I've been told that as of JDBC 4.2 we can directly pass `java.time` objects to the database. But what about the Three Ten Backport classes? Can you directly pass Three Ten Backport classes to JDBC as well?

For example, let's say you pass an `org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime` as an argument in a PreparedStatement. Would JDBC be able to handle this, the same way it accepts `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` as arguments?

Comment: This probably depends on your particular JDBC driver.

Comment: No vendor is obliged to support external libraries.

Comment: Most likely you can't use them, because the driver would need to explicitly support this.

Comment: I haven’t got the experience. I would suspect that you would need to convert to and from `java.sql` types. `DateTimeUtils` in the backport has methods for doing so. BTW, is there anything stopping you from upgrading to Java 8 (or 9, 10 or 11) so you can use the real thing?

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, we can't upgrade to Java 8 because one of our customers is using Java 7.